# No data found and error during execution of trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I created a simple trigger but I have a few problems.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_nb_ing
BEFORE INSERT ON RECETTE_INGREDIENT
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    cpt INT:=0;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(idIngredient) INTO cpt
    FROM RECETTE_INGREDIENT
    WHERE idRecette=:new.idRecette
    GROUP BY idRecette;

    IF (cpt>=20)
    THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20010, 'Trop d''ingrédients dans la recette');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Working when I make one insertion when they are 20 ingredients, but with the ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger

Also, when I'm trying the trigger when I insert my data, I have also the message:

```
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "gg.TRIGGER_NB_ING", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'gg.TRIGGER_NB_ING''
```

for each row in 'Recette_ingredient'.

Thank you

Comment: Remove `GROUP BY idRecette` clause to solve NO_DATA_FOUND problem. I doubt that ORA-04088 is caused by this trigger, my guess is that there is another trigger on this table in which you are doing some insert or update.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the full text of the error message. Are there other messages besides the ORA-04088? Thanks.

Comment: I remove the 'Group By' and I have now any problems for the insertion, thanks, but I have always the message ORA-04088 when the trigger is triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proximal clause of the no-data error is the `GROUP BY`.  When you have `GROUP BY`, Oracle returns one row per group.  If there are no groups, there are no rows.

By contrast, with no `GROUP BY`, Oracle always returns one row, so:

```
SELECT COUNT(idIngredient) INTO cpt
FROM RECETTE_INGREDIENT
WHERE idRecette = :new.idRecette;
```

However, that won't solve your other problem.  You are querying the table being modified.  This usually causes problems.  I would suggest that you keep the number of ingredients in the `RECETTES` table.  Check that the number is less than 20 and update it -- or return an error.

Answer (score 0):

OK, rewrite your trigger as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_nb_ing
  BEFORE INSERT ON RECETTE_INGREDIENT
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  cpt  INT := 0;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(idIngredient)
    INTO cpt
    FROM RECETTE_INGREDIENT
    WHERE idRecette = :new.idRecette;

  IF cpt >= 20 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20010, 'Trop d''ingrédients dans la recette');
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    NULL;
END;
```

I'm somewhat surprised this doesn't throw a "mutating table" error.

Best of luck.